# How to add loader in amp-story-player while stories content is loaded by the browser

Tags: amp-html, amp-story

I have a site with an html page having embedded amp-story-player.
Inside the amp-story-player there are multiple story urls.
Everything works fine except each story in the story-player takes 5 secs to load and it gives user an impression that there is no content.

Is there any way to add a loader while the content is loaded in the story ?

Comment: without seeing your code, it's easy to do. add an animated loader in the container DIV for each embedded story.

Comment: True. But when to hide loader. 
Meaning - How do I catch the event - that the page's story is loaded and running. 
So that I can hide the loader.

Comment: Try this: https://loading.io/css/ (CSS only; no JS)